# Load order polyglossia & newtx under XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, newtx

Why does loading `polyglosssia` first cause an option clash with `newtxtext` as in the following example? And is there a way to avoid the option while still loading `polyglossia` first? (Loading it after works OK.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX    
\documentclass{article}

% This load order --> option clash for \usepackage{newtxtext}:
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguages{french,german,polish,russian}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ntxtlf}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % only if you want to load other opentype fonts.
\usepackage{newtxtext}

% This load order OK:
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
%\setotherlanguages{french,german,polish,russian}

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{PT Serif}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Their names in Cyrillic are \textrussian{Алекс\'{а}ндров}, \textrussian{Т\'{и}хонов}, and \textrussian{Урыс\'{o}н}.

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448589/13492 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210276/13492.

Comment: the option clash is not from newtxtext but from fontspec - polyglossia already loads it. Beside this: you shouldn't use newtxtext and fontenc with T1+T2a with xelatex, these are settings for pdflatex.

Comment: Using newtxtext and fontenc is what the author of newtx recommends to use the newtx fonts with XeLaTeX.

Comment: I see in the docu a recommendation how to use newtx**math** with xelatex but nothing about newtx**text**.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Correct, the docs show libertine as the text font. The use of newtxtext with XeLaTeX was provided in a private communication by the newtx author.

Comment: if you use `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}` in xelatex then certainly all hyphenation will be wrong as xelatex loads no hyphenation patterns for 8-bit encodings.

Comment: but in this case you anyway undo that by loading fontspec (which will re-set the encoding to TU)  but  can  you not simply use TeX Gryre Termes via fontspec rather than the derived newtx 8bit pdftex font family?

Comment: Yes, I can use TeX Gyre Termes instead.

Answer (score 2):

The setup is much simpler. Just remember to redeclare the `operators` font.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[vvarbb]{newtxmath}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguages{french,german,polish,russian}

\setmainfont{Tempora}[
  NFSSFamily=tempora,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{tempora}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

Their names in Cyrillic are \textrussian{Алекс\'{а}ндров}, 
\textrussian{Т\'{и}хонов}, and \textrussian{Урыс\'{o}н}.

Some in text formula $a+b=c-\sqrt[3]{2}$
\[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\qquad
\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1
\]

\end{document}
```

The Tempora font is available in TeX Live and is a clone of Times supporting Cyrillic.

[image]

Comment: How close is Tempora to newtxtext, in comparision with how close TeX Gyre Termes is to newtxtext?

Comment: @murray I see no difference between the three, as far as Latin characters are concerned.

Comment: The fontspec docs (page 5) say that file tempora.fontspec is read by fontspec whenever tempora is loaded as a font, and that file includes the options `Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = Tempora-Regular,
  BoldFont = Tempora-Bold,
  ItalicFont = Tempora-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = Tempora-BoldItalic`

Comment: @murray Oh, that's good news!

Comment: What needs to be changed if, indeed, I want to use TeXGyre Termes as the text font?